# watermark upload image without resize image width height

Tags: php, image-resizing, watermark

so my following code is working like if i upload image it will resize image to 720x450 and then watermark it. but i wish not to modify the width and height and put the watermark at the bottom right of an image of any size

if someone could help me out here?

```
$image_path = "../images/watermark.png";
function watermark_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    global $image_path;
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width = 720; $height = 450;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
    list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($image_path);        
    $pos_x = $width - $w_width; 
    $pos_y = $height - $w_height;
    imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 90);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}
```

appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing manual height and width, Just assign the original height ans width of image

```
$image_path = "../images/watermark.png";
function watermark_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    global $image_path;
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width = $owidth; $height = $oheight;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
    list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($image_path);        
    $pos_x = $width - $w_width; 
    $pos_y = $height - $w_height;
    imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 90);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}
```

Try this will work as you expected.

for more info check here http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: appreciate mate but the watermark i need it at the bottom its doing it at top left

Comment: @johrampong  set the $pos_x  and $pos_y values according to your need. It will work

Comment: still coming at top left mate

Comment: @johrampong  imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, Expected_x_Pos, expected_y_pos, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);  update your code like it
Expected_x_Pos - will be your required x value
Expected_y_Pos - will be your required y value